# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { happy1.js:29

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error message when importing and exporting from one JS file to another.

```
export const http = new EasyHTTP();
import { http } from './http';
```

any idea why this would throw this kind of error message?

Comment: Does whatever environment you are running this code in support ES6 modules?

Comment: There's no line 29 in this code. What's on line 29?

Comment: Bergi- I'm using visual code. how do i check?